# SQL query to match the occurrence of 1 or more digit

Tags: sql

My table has column with below data

Optional (8)

Optional (5)

Optional (2)

Optional (10)

Optional (6)

Optional (2) (2)

Optional (9)

Optional (11)

I would like to know how to write a query to retrieve the values which match with

Optional (followed by any number of digit)

So the output should not have 'Optional (2) (2)' since it has ') (' in between.

Please help....

Comment: What database are you using?  It is important to tag a question with the correct database.  In this case, the necessary string functions depend on the database.

Answer (score 0):

well, if you know it's always going to be ) ( then...

```
SELECT * from table where field like 'Optional (%)'
```

but we still need to check that the data inside is numeric...

So a regular expression would probably work best.

what RDBMS?